# Django данные в html templates в зависимоти от роли пользователя

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Подскажите, как в проекте, которые растет и в котором добавляются новые роли организовать вывод данных для html шаблонов.

На первом этапе с 3 очевидными ролями, все было организовано через `if`-statements в самих шаблонах. Пример:

```py
{% if user_role == "superuser"%}
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
         .....
{% endif %}
```

Либо через `if-elif-else`.

Количество элементов на странице и количество ролей растет. Это значит, что распределение данных, которые должны быть показаны, становится не удобным в обслуживании и расширении.

Существует, ли, паттерн проектирования для `django`, который описывает и решает данную проблему? Первое, что приходит в голову - это создать нексколько html шаблонов и подтягивать их в зависимости от роли.

Answer (score 1):

Использовать декораторы для функций вью, если модер или админ то:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

@staff_member_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Для обычных зарегистрированных пользователей:

```
@login_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: таки это и сделано, вопрос о том что для каждой роли нужен свой template, вы это тоже подразумеваете?